# Google yolo The client origin is not permitted to use this API

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, google-identity

I am still getting the Google yolo The client origin is not permitted to use this API error even after google have approved the request.

Even the OAuth Consent screen is showing as published. Anyone have any idea why this error still occurs?

Code:

```
window.onGoogleYoloLoad = (googleyolo) => {
    // The 'googleyolo' object is ready for use.
    console.log("Googleyolo is ready to use.");
    const retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve({
        supportedAuthMethods: [
            "https://accounts.google.com",
            "googleyolo://id-and-password"
        ],
        supportedIdTokenProviders: [
            {
                uri: "https://accounts.google.com",
                clientId: "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            }
        ]
    }).....
```

Comment: Please include your code and relevant logs in the question.

Comment: const retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve({
            supportedAuthMethods: [
                "https://accounts.google.com",
                "googleyolo://id-and-password"
            ],
            supportedIdTokenProviders: [
                {
                    uri: "https://accounts.google.com",
                    clientId: "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                }
            ]
        })

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by authorizing your current redirect URL in your google developer console.
 Enter your development/server deployed URL into google console "Authorized JavaScript origins"